# Setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache vs just Apache Event MPM

Tags: django, apache, nginx, mod-wsgi

In the Django [docs for setting up mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration), the tutorial notes:

> Django doesn’t serve files itself; it leaves that job to whichever Web
>   server you choose.
>
> We recommend using a separate Web server – i.e., one that’s not also
>   running Django – for serving media. Here are some good choices:
>
> - Nginx
> - A stripped-down version of Apache

I understand this might be due to wasted resources when Apache spawns new processes to serve each static file, which Nginx avoids. However, Apache's (newish?) Event MPM seems to act similar to an Nginx instance handing off requests to an Apache worker mpm. Therefore I'd like to ask: instead of setting up Nginx to be a reverse proxy for Apache, would using an Apache Event MPM be sufficient for serving static files in Apache?

Answer (score 3):

Apache doesn't spawn a new process for each static file. Apache keeps persistent processes to handle concurrent and subsequent requests just like nginx. The difference is that nginx uses a full async model, whereas Apache relies on processes and/or threading for concurrency, although event MPM uses an async model for initial request acceptance and keep alive connections now. For the majority of people, Apache alone is still a more than acceptable solution. So don't get ahead of yourself if you are just starting out and think you need a Google/Facebook scale solution from the outset.

More important than separate web server is that if using Apache/mod_wsgi, serve the static files under a different host name. That way you avoid heavy weight cookie information being sent for all static file requests. You can do this using virtual hosts in Apache. Also ensure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi for running the Django application as that is a better architecture and provides lots more options for setting timeouts so you can have your application recover from various situations which might otherwise cause the server to lock up when overloaded.

For a system which provides a better out of the box configuration and experience than using Apache/mod_wsgi directly and configuring it yourself, look at using `mod_wsgi-express`.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/using-modwsgi-express-with-django.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/integrating-modwsgi-express-as-django.html

Comment: can you point me to a resource where I can learn what you mean by "serve the static files under a different host name"?

Comment: See ``STATIC_URL`` setting. Then set up Apache with virtual host or separate web server using separate host name. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#static-files and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

The advice about separating the webservers has two advantages. One clearly outlined by Graham. The other is "predictable resource consumption".

The number of resources per HTML page differ. Leaving one webserver to serve the application and the other to serve static resources, has the advantage that you know exactly how many concurrent visitors you can serve: the `MaxClients` setting of Apache.

If this slows down the loading of images, those webservers need very few modules and no measurable amount of CPU power so a one core machine with SSD disks is all you need and scaling is cheap.

As Graham indicates it starts with a `STATIC_URL` that has a different hostname. Run it at the same server at the start. When scaling up, tie that hostname to a reverse proxy that serves from several image server backend machines.